# Is there any reason why onreadystatechange wont do anything for css header link in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, header, onreadystatechange

I made a bookmarklet that loads several header. some JS some css. after i create the header element i do a `onreadystatechange` to check when the included header was loaded.

However for some reason this check doesnt work for safari for the css headers.

Here is the code for it:

```
var CssScript = document.createElement("link");
CssScript.href = "http://domain.com/css/bookmarklet.css";
CssScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
CssScript.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
CssScript.setAttribute('media', 'all');
CssScript.setAttribute('id', 'yk_bookmarklet_css');
CssScript.onload = CssScript.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log("asdfasdfasdfasdf");
    if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == "loaded" || this.readyState == "complete")) {
        loaded_headers++;
        console.log('Next2');
        if(loaded_headers >= total_headers){
            done = true;
            $.getJSON("http://www.shopsavr.com/bookmarklet_getjson_functions.php?jsoncallback=?", {'url' : encodeURIComponent(document.URL)},
                function(data){
                    collections = data.collecitons;
                    product_found = data.product;
                    uID = data.uID;
                    url = data.url;
                    window.mbm = false;
                    initMyBookmarklet();
                });
        }
    }
};
```

This works perfectly in IE,FF,chrome,Opera - it only fails on safari.

Comment: Maybe set the HREF after you set the onload event?

Comment: Just tried and it did nothing. however just to avoid confusion. where to add it ? inside the function ? after the = ?